# Get notified by just mail

Tags: magento-1.8, stock, notify-me

I am trying to create a "Notify me" feature if the stock is unavailable.

On search on admin panel, I could find only that a user should `sign up / log in` to get notified about the stock availability.

But I just want to let the user (*a guest*) enter only his/her email address to get notified.

How should I do this?

Please give suggestions..

**EDIT**:

I have got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735592/1577396), which gives me a way to start.

Till now what I did is added the following code in my template file which is creating a url for redirect (*thinking to do it in ajax way*).

```
<?php
      $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
      $base64 = strtr(base64_encode($actual_link), '+/=', '-_,'); 
      $postUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/efk/productalert/add/stock/product_id/" . $simpleProduct->getId() . "/uenc/". $base64; 
?>
```

In the above code, `efk` is my project folder name.

After this, I have gone to `productalert/add/stock` controller method i.e `stockAction()` which is calling `sign up / login` form (*I think so*) using `$model->save();`.

How should I disable this save calling and add my own small overlay which holds a textbox to enter a email address?

Comment: This seems like a too generic question to me, almost like a request to write an extension. Try splitting it up into "how to display an overlay", "how to add guests for stock alerts", "how to build internal links in templates" and so on.

Comment: @Vinai.. sorry I am not asking for code.. if you just give me directions that would be enough.. (not really.. but I will try)

Comment: @Mr_Green Vinai just described the steps you need to take in order to build your extension.

Comment: @FlorinelChis honestly, that is not helpful for me.. why can't mage dev's help me here? they are just showing me some extension to use which I can't in my current situation. Anyway, the response which I got on Stackoverflow is far better than what I got here.. I am trying that now.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20214452/1577396).

Answer (score 0):

Aheadworks have an extension which can do this, along with other notifications, and it's setup to allow Guests to subscribe. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-updates-notifications-by-aheadworks.html

Comment: That is not free... I am a developer not shop-owner.. :). I can't say to my client like.. "I can't do this please buy this extension.." right..? that is just like killing my stomach.

Comment: Can you not pass the costs on to your client? I'm a developer too and I'd rather pay $90 than spend a day of my time.

Comment: I meant no disrespect to you.. you might be right.. but my perception is different.. I can't do this..

Comment: @Mr_Green if you always applied the same logic would you also write Magento from scratch? The argument is not that you can't do it but working in the interest of your client which could mean it is more economical to start with an existing implementation (free or not).

Comment: I am not saying that this post is not helpful for everyone.. it is just not helpful for me in my present situation. btw, I got some free extension.. which needs some modifications to make it work like I want to. [**link**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/out-of-stock-notification-7896.html). (_working on it_)

Comment: I'm not sure on what budget you are, but $90,- isn't a lot of money, even if you only charge $10,- an hour, the paid module would probably benefit you. They have battle-tested their module, all quirks are already fixed and since it is aheadWorks you also get decent support. To answer your question, there is no easy default way to achieve this without building this your self.

Comment: @PaulHachmang yes I am trying to build on my own but not possible with you guys help.. just give me directions what to do and in which file I should do.. that would give me a start atleast. My second alternate is the free extension which I linked above in my comments. Though it is doing what I want but it seems to be only for configurable products. but in my case, I need this "notify" stuff for simple products. In my project, each configurable product has three types of simple products. and the extension works if and only if I explicitly enable the "out of stock"  through admin panel.